# Styled-components generating error "A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have"

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

My app is rendering locally and throwing this error "A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have"

I am trying to use styled-components.

I have tried installing styled-components@3.3.3

When I remove the below index code it works.

When I include the code, the DOM is just a white screen and console throws the error.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const SectionGroup = styled.div`
    background: black;
    height: 720px;
`

const SectionLogo = styled.img``

const SectionTitleGroup = styled.div``

const SectionTitle = styled.h3``

const SectionText = styled.p``

const Section = props => {
    <SectionGroup image={props.image}>
        <SectionLogo src={props.logo} />
        <SectionTitleGroup>
            <SectionTitle>{props.title}</SectionTitle>
            <SectionText>{props.text}</SectionText>
        </SectionTitleGroup>
    </SectionGroup>
}

export default Section




//MY INDEX FILE HAS THIS

import Section from '../components/Section'

  <Section 
    image={require('../images/wallpaper2.jpg')}
    logo={require('../images/logo-react.png')}
    title="React for Designers"
    text="THIS IS SOME TEXT"
  />
```

I expect the DOM to render the page but it doesn't.

"A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of code

```
const Section = props => {
    <SectionGroup image={props.image}>
        <SectionLogo src={props.logo} />
        <SectionTitleGroup>
            <SectionTitle>{props.title}</SectionTitle>
            <SectionText>{props.text}</SectionText>
        </SectionTitleGroup>
    </SectionGroup>
}
```

should be

```
const Section = props => (
    <SectionGroup image={props.image}>
        <SectionLogo src={props.logo} />
        <SectionTitleGroup>
            <SectionTitle>{props.title}</SectionTitle>
            <SectionText>{props.text}</SectionText>
        </SectionTitleGroup>
    </SectionGroup>
)
```

Your code does not return anything, because you're using `{ }`

Use `() => ( )` or `() => { return (...JSX) }`